# Polya-Szego Problems and Theorems in Analysis Q.121 in "Some Properties of Real Functions"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, not constant and $f(a) =f(b) =0.$ Show that there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $|f'(c)| > \dfrac{4}{(b-a)^2}\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx$

My attempt: By using the mean value theorem on $f$ over $[a, \frac{a+b}{2}]$ and $[\frac{a+b}{2}, b] $ we can find $c_1 \in (a, \frac{a+b}{2})$ and $c_2 \in (\frac{a+b}{2}, b)$ such that $f'(c_1) = \dfrac{2(f(\frac{a+b}{2})-f(a))}{b-a}$ and $f'(c_2) = \dfrac{2(f(b)-f(\frac{a+b}{2}))}{b-a}$ so $f'(c_1)= -f'(c_2).$ Since $f$ is differentiable on $[a, b]$ it is continuous on $[a, b]$ so there exists $M >0$ such that $\forall \, x \in [a, b], |f(x)| \leq M$ from which we get that $|f'(c_1)|=|f'(c_2)| \leq \dfrac{4M}{b-a}$ which isn't very promising.

In the authors' solution shown in the picture, they assume $f$ to have bounded derivative. So I have one question:

If a function is differentiable on a closed and bounded interval and is equal at its endpoints, does that mean that the derivative is bounded? (For example if $f(x) = x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ then $f$ is differentiable on $[0, 1]$ but its derivative is unbounded on $[0, 1]$. So does the equality at the endpoints force $f$ to have bounded derivative?

[image: Below is the authors' solution.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. Take your function $f(x) = x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ in $[0,1/\sqrt{\pi}]$. Then $f(0)=f(1/\sqrt{\pi})=0$.

Concerning your problem. Distinguish two cases. Case 1: if $f'$ is unbounded in $[a,b]$ then you can definitely find $c$ such that the inequality holds. So the difficult case is when $f'$ is bounded and now you can follow the solutions.